# Magento 1.9 CSV import using categoy id

Tags: magento-1, import, csv

In the category column of the CSV ("_category"), how do I use the ID number of the category instead of the full path?

I did google this but I think the results were for 1.7 as the field name was "category_id" and when I changed it to this, i got an error.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, there is no way to do this with core magento. You have to provide the full path of the categories

```
Electronics/Cameras/Digital Cameras
```

this is a problem, especially when you have categories with the same name :-/